# Webservice request working in SOAP UI, but failing in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a web service, which is working perfectly with SOAP UI, but throwing 500 error when tried to from JMETER 2.1.3.I am using SOAP/XML RPC Request, another open endpoint(http://www.webservicex.net/whois.asmx?WSDL) with jmeter is working perfectly fine. Is there any setup to be done with my service to get it invoked from JMETER?

**SOAP/XML RPC Request:**

[image]

Sampler Request

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-03-19 19:20:54 IST
Load time: 531
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 531
Size in bytes: 205
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 205
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 19 Mar 2016 13:48:24 GMT
Connection: close


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>Method is not available : Unauthorized</faultstring>          
</soap:Fault>
```

Comment: Your error message says the request is unauthorized.  Do you know what type of authorization the service requires?  Do you have any authorization setup in your JMeter flow?

Comment: No authorization required for this method. Just a simple hello service, which could be accessed from SOAP UI with default settings.as updated earlier, the same JMETER, could access a open endpoint.

Comment: I would try running both requests (SoapUI and JMeter) through a proxy to log what the request XML looks like.  On a Unix system, netcat (nc) can be used to make a simple proxy to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture requests send by SoapUI and JMeter and determine what is the difference.

My expectation is that you're missing a HTTP Header, maybe [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html)  or [Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or something like that. Headers can be manipulated using [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

Comment: Dmitri: Wireshark helped us to find the missing header SoapAction to the HTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when loading a WSDL with SOAPUI and then send request, will work properly. In JMETER instead, will no be as easy as SOAPUI due to JMETER is not configured from loading the WSDL, you have to be very strict on specify each parameter as protocol, host, and Path will be the most important, even if you "CTRL+C" from SOAPUI and CTRL+V to JMETER you may get some extra characters (like &). So, after adding all parameters (authorization, accept encoding, and any other) still getting the error 500... you may need to verify your "Path" on JMETER.